# Is there a way for pip to install only new dependencies in an updated requirements.txt

Tags: python, pip

```
pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt
```

repeats the installation process for all the previously installed dependencies which can be a pain when I have a huge list of dependencies (like more than 30?)

Isn't there a way to check an updated requirements.txt and install only specific dependencies that have been included into the requirements.txt file since the previous installation attempt?

I find this to be a real shortcoming of pip (or using pip in virtualenv for that matter). Do not like the repetitive installation nature of pip at all.

Comment: pip does not install already installed packaged unless you force it to using `--upgrade` option.

Comment: pip also downloads any requirements specified by URL every time it runs, presumably because it can't know if the version at the remote URL has changed.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As mentioned by Piotr in the comments above, if "--upgrade" is not included in the command, already installed python packages are left alone.