# pip install -r: install only new packages

Tags: python, installation, pip, package

Let's say my `requirements.txt` file is:

```
diff-match-patch==20121119
django-braces==1.4.0
django-crispy-forms==1.4.0
```

I install all the software with the following command:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Now let's say I add two packages:

```
diff-match-patch==20121119
django-braces==1.4.0
django-crispy-forms==1.4.0
django-custom-user==0.4
django-import-export==0.2.3
```

If I want to install the new packages only, that is, only the last two ones, what command should I use?
If I run again the command `pip install -r requirements.txt`, it's going to download and try to install everything, including the packages already installed!

Comment: It shouldn't. https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#caching  _"When making any HTTP request pip will first check its local cache to determine if it has a suitable response stored for that request which has not expired. If it does then it simply returns that response and doesn't make the request."_

Comment: I guess it depends on whether or not the cache has expired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're worried about only upgrading certain packages, you can upgrade packages manually with `pip install -U <package>`.

If your concern is not freshly installing all of your dependencies every time, don't worry. If you run `pip install -r requirements.txt` without the `-U` (or `--upgrade`) flag, it won't try to update previously installed packages, as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9050411/2267428).